# Custom output wp list category

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Here is the output from the wp list categories:

```
Personal Area
    Allergy Asthma Dust
        Restaurant
        Cafe
        Bar
    Chemical & Smoke
        Airport
    Dump & Mold
    Pet & Dander
Commercial Area
    Commercial child 1
        Commercial child 1-2
        Commercial child 1-3
    Commercial child 2
        Commercial child 2-1
```

This is my code on front-page.php

```
<?php wp_list_categories('taxonomy=product_category&hide_empty=0&orderby=id&title_li=');?>
```

The category have 2 depth child. I want to custom the output html with background images each categories level and on click function to show each children

This is the html i want to added in wp list catgeories :

```
 <div class="row">
      <div class='col-md-6 pr-0'>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="personal text-right">
            <p>I want to improve air quality in my</p>
               <h4>PERSONAL AREA</h4>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class='col-md-6 pl-0'>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="commercial text-left">
            <p>I want to have better air quality in my</p>
              <h4>COMMERCIAL AREA</h4>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is for the children html when click parent category:

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class='col-md-12 pr-0'>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="personal text-right">
            <h4>What do you want to get rid off ?</h4>
            <p>Allergy Asthma Dust</p>
            <p>Chemical & Smoke</p>
            <p>Dump & Mold</p>
            <p>Pet & Dander</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
```

Here is the updated php code

```
      <?php                          
          $product_categories = get_terms( array(
              'taxonomy' => 'product_category',
              'hide_empty' => false,
              'orderby' => 'ID',
          ) );
          $cnt = 0;
          foreach($product_categories as $product_category) :   
              $cnt++;  
              if( count(get_term_children( $product_category->term_id, 'product_category' )) == 0) $catlink = 'document.location.href=\''.get_term_link( $product_category->term_id, 'product_category' ).'\''; else $catlink = 'toggleChildCategories('.$product_category->term_id.')'; // check last child category and change link

              if($product_category->parent == 0 && $cnt % 2 != 0) { // top-level parent
                  echo '<div class="col-md-6 pr-0 cat-parent-'.$product_category->term_id.' cat-parent cat-parent-'.$product_category->parent.' show">
                      <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="'.$catlink.'">
                          <div class="personal text-right">
                              <p>'.$product_category->description.'</p>
                              <h4>'.$product_category->name.'</h4>
                          </div>
                      </a>
                  </div>'; 
              }
              if($product_category->parent == 0 && $cnt % 2 == 0) { // top-level parent
                echo '<div class="col-md-6 pl-0 cat-parent-'.$product_category->term_id.' cat-parent cat-parent-'.$product_category->parent.' show">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="'.$catlink.'">
                        <div class="commercial text-left">
                            <p>'.$product_category->description.'</p>
                            <h4>'.$product_category->name.'</h4>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>'; 
              }
              else { // child
                if($product_category->term_id == 4) {
                  echo '<div class="col-md-12 cat-parent-'.$product_category->term_id.' cat-children cat-item-'.$product_category->parent.' hide">
                      <h2>What do you want to get rid of ?</h2>
                  </div>';
                }
                if($product_category->term_id == 10) {
                  $parentname=get_term_by('id', $product_category->parent, 'product_category');
                  echo '<div class="col-md-12 cat-parent-'.$product_category->term_id.' cat-children cat-item-'.$product_category->parent.' hide">
                      <h2>Where do you want to get rid of</h2>
                      <h3>'.$parentname->name.'</h3>
                  </div>';
                }
                  echo '<div class="col-md-2 border2 cat-parent-'.$product_category->term_id.' cat-children cat-item-'.$product_category->parent.' hide">
                      <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="'.$catlink.'">
                          <h5>'.$product_category->name.'</h5>
                      </a>
                  </div>';        
              }
          endforeach;     
          ?>
```

Comment: Hope you already achieved everything and just need to add background image to each category?

Comment: I want add image background each level category, when user choose 'personal area' will be to the next level category child with different background image, I try using the get categories term but confuse to separate parent category and child category, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36615440/get-all-categories-of-a-custom-post-type . I confuse add some code in foreach to separate the parent category and child category @OutsourceWordPress

Comment: Do you want to show the images dynamically? In case, are you using any plugin to add an image to the category?

Comment: The images not dynamically, I'm just want add image background per level category and I'm not using plugin for add an image, @OutsourceWordPress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get_terms()` to achieve a custom layout.

```
<?php                       
$product_categories = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_category',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'orderby' => 'ID',
) );

foreach($product_categories as $product_category) :         
    if($product_category->parent > 0) $hideshow='cat-item-'.$product_category->parent.' hide'; else $hideshow='cat-parent cat-parent-'.$product_category->parent.' show'; // hide child categories and append parent category
    echo '<div class="col-md-6 pr-0 cat-parent-'.$product_category->term_id.' '.$hideshow.'">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="toggleChildCategories('.$product_category->term_id.');">
            <div class="personal text-right">
                <p>'.$product_category->description.'</p>
                <h4>'.$product_category->name.'</h4>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>';        
endforeach;     
?>
```

Add this JS which would toggle appropriate child categories when the parent category clicked.

```
<script>
function toggleChildCategories(catid)
{
    jQuery('.cat-parent-'+catid).hide(); // hide particular parent
    jQuery('.cat-parent').hide(); // hide all parents
    jQuery('.cat-item-'+catid).slideToggle(100); // toggle child
}
</script>
```

Use this CSS to hide all the child categories initially.

```
<style>
.hide{display:none;}
</style>
```

Hope this helps. But please note that this is just an idea and you need to make necessary alterations.

**Update:** Different templates for parent (top level alone) and child categories.

```
<?php                          
$product_categories = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'orderby' => 'ID',
) );

foreach($product_categories as $product_category) :   
    if( count(get_term_children( $product_category->term_id, 'product_category' )) == 0) $catlink = 'document.location.href=\''.get_term_link( $product_category->term_id, 'product_category' ).'\''; else $catlink = 'toggleChildCategories('.$product_category->term_id.')'; // check last child category and change link

    if($product_category->parent == 0) { // top-level parent
        echo '<div class="col-md-6 pr-0 pl-0 cat-parent-'.$product_category->term_id.' cat-parent cat-parent-'.$product_category->parent.' show">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="'.$catlink.'">
                <div class="personal text-right">
                    <p>'.$product_category->description.'</p>
                    <h4>'.$product_category->name.'</h4>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>'; 
    }
    else { // child
        echo '<div class="col-md-2 border2 cat-parent-'.$product_category->term_id.' cat-item-'.$product_category->parent.' hide">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="'.$catlink.'">
                <h5>'.$product_category->name.'</h5>
            </a>
        </div>';        
    }
endforeach;     
?>
```

Comment: wahh awesome thankss, but for click interaction, I try using this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49644866/display-child-categories-on-click when click second parent child ( allergy asthma dust ) the children is already open and won't to close by click. How to modified the jquery ? @OutsourceWordPress

Comment: I want added html boostrap too in the each level catgeory. updated the code html in the question. Is it possible add it in the wp list catgeries ? @OutsourceWordpress

Comment: No, you can't achieve this using `wp_list_categories()`, try my updated answer.

Comment: Oh ok, I will give it try, @OutsourceWordpress

Comment: I made couple of changes now, place the updated code inside your `<div class="row">`.

Comment: Wah awesome it works! but when I'm choose Personal area how to made fade off effect to next child ? I'm updated for the html children @OutsourceWordpress

Comment: If you want 'fade' effect instead of 'slide', just change `jQuery('.cat-item-'+catid).slideToggle(100);` to `jQuery('.cat-item-'+catid).fadeToggle(1000);` in the `toggleChildCategories()` JS function.

Comment: Ok, how to change the html template when show children category ? I want template html different from the parent catgeory @OutsourceWordpress

Comment: `if($product_category->parent == 0)` denotes top-level categories and `if($product_category->parent > 0)` denotes child categories. You can use this condition to change the layout.

Comment: Thanks for your help @OutsourceWordpress , How to hide the current category when click it ? example when I click parent category it will be show the children category but the parent category will be hidden.

Comment: Updated the answer to hide the parent (changed `$hideshow` variable as well as `toggleChildCategories()` function).

Comment: Thank you for your fast reponse @OutsourceWordpress , It works but only current click category it hidden, I want all parent category hidden not just the current category click. Is It possible ?

Comment: Updated the answer again to hide all parents (changed `$hideshow` variable as well as `toggleChildCategories()` function).

Comment: Thanks @OutsourceWordpress , Could you help for different template children catgeory and parent category ? I have been update the php code I try in the question,

Comment: Check the 'Update' part of the answer - but note that only a different template for top level parent and rest would be child.

Comment: wah cool @OutsourceWordpress , How to give permalink for the last child ? I want to redirect the last child to the category page.

Comment: Check the 'Update' part of the answer again.

Comment: Thank you @OutsourceWordpress , How to give uniqe title in the third child catgeory like this one https://prnt.sc/l8asrb I want to print the user catgeory choose too like 'allergy asthma dust'

Comment: Just note down the taxonomy ID (say, 5) from WordPress admin and you can add like `<?php if($product_category->term_id == 5) echo 'Where do you want to get rid of '; ?>` before `<h5>'.$product_category->name.'</h5>`.

Comment: It works! @OutsourceWordpress, But let's say I choose category 'allergy' and how to pass the value to next child category ? so I can print the 'allergy' on the next title child.

Comment: Do you want to just print parent category name before child category name?

Comment: yes @OutsourceWordpress, so user know what category they choose before,

Comment: Just add this code `$parentname=get_term_by('id', $product_category->parent, 'product_category'); echo $parentname->name;` in your child template code.

Comment: How to make the if($product_category->term_id == 10) more dynamically ? Because when I choose another category, the title not shown up. I have been update some php code in the question @OutsourceWordpress

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182192/discussion-between-outsource-wordpress-and-eko-bayu).